# Javascript canvas context

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to bulid Snake game using HTML and Javascript, but I have this problem:

```
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fillRect(
    apple.x * BLOCK_SIZE + 1,
    apple.y * BLOCK_SIZE + 1,
    BLOCK_SIZE - 1,
    BLOCK_SIZE - 1
);

context.fillStyle = 'lime';
for(var i = 0; i < snake.body.length; i++) {
    context.fillRect(
        snake.body[i].x * BLOCK_SIZE + 1,
        snake.body[i].y * BLOCK_SIZE + 1,
        BLOCK_SIZE - 1,
        BLOCK_SIZE - 1
    );
}
```

The red one is my apple and the lime one is my snake. When my snake touch the apple, it goes beneath it, so it'll looks like my game stops for a frame. Is there any way to make my snake always on top of my apple?

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with your drawing; It's likely to be a problem with your _collision with apple_ detection. Instead of checking it at the end of the frame, try checking it at the beginning. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Can you provide a complete example of your code

Answer (score 1):

If you are drawing in the order you show in your code, the snake goes on top of the apple...

The only way the snake goes beneath the apple is if you are drawing those elements in a different order, as far as I can see your code is good.

Here is a sample code snippet:

```js
const BLOCK_SIZE = 12
var apple = {x:9, y:5}
var snake = {body: [{x:1, y:1}, {x:1, y:2}, {x:1, y:3}, {x:2, y:3}, {x:2, y:4}, {x:2, y:5}]}

var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
var context = canvas.getContext("2d")

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fillRect( 
    apple.x * BLOCK_SIZE+1, 
    apple.y * BLOCK_SIZE+1, 
    BLOCK_SIZE-1, BLOCK_SIZE-1 );

  context.fillStyle = 'lime';
  for (var i = 0; i < snake.body.length; i++) {
    context.fillRect( 
      snake.body[i].x * BLOCK_SIZE+1, 
      snake.body[i].y * BLOCK_SIZE+1, 
      BLOCK_SIZE-1, BLOCK_SIZE-1 );
  }
}

function loop() {
  const last = snake.body.at(-1).x
  snake.body.push({x:last+1, y:5})
  draw()
}

draw()
setInterval(loop, 800);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="240" height="140"></canvas>
```